# Forward a call from landline to did number

Tags: asterisk, voip, ivr

Is there any way  that i can forward a call from my landline number to my DID number and handle that call with asterisk code??

Is this type of forwarding possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 posible variants

1) Ask your landline provider support about number portability(depend of country and provider) or forward number to sip.

2) Put on your line FXO gateway device(pstn2sip gate, $100-$200 cost) and setup it to work as did for asterisk.